# Can I read HTTP Requests using casperjs and phantomjs

Tags: web, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm new to casperjs and phantomjs. I am just running a crawler to read the HTTP Requests (may be using Fiddler or Network debugger). I just want to know, can we get the http requests data while opening a page using casperjs and phantomjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `onResourceRequested` to get all the requests coming in, including headers. (You can use `onResourceReceived` to see what headers are being sent.)

The code below is for PhantomJS, and shows you everything available.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, networkRequest) 
{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(requestData));
};

page.onResourceReceived = function(response) 
{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
};

page.open(url,function()
{
    phantom.exit();
});
```

For CasperJS `casper.page` is used for the same thing (assuming you created an object called `casper`).